Problems with Google Functions
I have had a function in the tool for some time where I process meta ads data and save it in tables within Google Cloud itself, causing the expiration of a meta token, when I make the change and try to save "Save and redeploy" a popup comes up saying that it is processing the update, then it closes and the button that was previously unavailable because theoretically the process was occurring becomes available again and nothing else happens, no error or success message.
enter image description here
enter image description here
This popup stops there and nothing happens in the end
I tried to contact Google support, but as my level is basic they referred me to forums, which I personally find ridiculous, given that I am theoretically facing technical problems.

Guys, after analyzing the requests made by Google using Devtools, I noticed that the error apparently was that I allocated too much memory to my region, so it just reduced the memory and everything worked fine.
Unfortunately, the Google Cloud front did not handle this error and thus did not return anything to the client side, meaning they only had a certain technical level to identify such a simple problem.
